# Setting build path in project.properties

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, build

I've a android project which is built using ant (ant debug/release) to generate application executable. The dependent projects path has been set from project.properties as follows:

```
android.library.reference.1=../../../backup/cocos2d-x-2.2.1/cocos2dx/platform/android/java

android.library.reference.2=../../../backup/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
```

But The path is relative to my system. I wanted to modify the path with some environment variables like:

```
android.library.reference.1=$COCOS_HOME/cocos2dx/platform/android/java
```

But it doesn't works.
Do I have to define it somewhere in ant build file? 
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on Mads's answer, you can use environment variables in subsequently loaded property files by first loading the environment variables with the `<property environment="env"/>` element in your build.xml file before loading from local.properties or project.properties. After this you can use environment variables in your project.properties in the following manner:

```
android.library.reference.1=${env.COCOS_HOME}/cocos2dx/platform/android/java
```

assuming COCOS_HOME is an environment variable.

Strangely, the library reference paths only seem to allow relative paths on my windows system (what about *nixes?), so my environment variable `COCOS2DX_ROOT='D:\softwares\ANDROID\cocos2d-x-2.2'` doesn't work.

**There is I think a neater way to address the problem of environment-specific paths**, and this method uses the **local.properties** file.

Just create a local.properties file (if it doesn't already exist) alongside project.properties, and define machine specific paths there. For example, here are the contents for my **local.properties** and **project.properties** files:

**local.properties**

```
COCOS2DX_ROOT_RELATIVE=../../../cocos2d-x-2.2
ANDROID_ROOT_RELATIVE=../../../adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030/sdk
# location of the SDK. This is only used by Ant
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
sdk.dir=D:\\softwares\\ANDROID\\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\\sdk
```

**project.properties**

```
android.library.reference.1=${COCOS2DX_ROOT_RELATIVE}/cocos2dx/platform/android/java
android.library.reference.2=${ANDROID_ROOT_RELATIVE}/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
```

Since local.properties is loaded first in the build.xml file, properties defined there can be referenced in project.properties with the `${...}` notation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **COCOS_HOME** defined as an environment variable, you can load the environment variables with the [property task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) and the environment attribute.

> By setting the *environment* attribute with a prefix to use.
>       Properties will be defined for every environment variable by
>       prefixing the supplied name and a period to the name of the variable.

You will need to be sure to load the environment variables prior to loading your properties files, so that the property reference in the properties file is expanded to have the value of the property.

For example:

```
<property environment="env"/>
<echo message="COCOS_HOME is set to = ${env.COCOS_HOME}"/>
<property file="android.properties"/>
<echo message="android.library.reference.1 is set to = ${android.library.reference.1}" />
```

Comment: Do you mean, I've to define a property in build.xml and can access like ${env.COCOS_HOME} ? I've tried that and it didn't work, only relative paths work. Is something getting wrong on understanding your answer?

Comment: Yes, that is how you would reference it. Also, be sure that you have loaded the environment variables in a property task prior to loading your properties file. Also, try using the echo task to see/verify what the values are being set to.

Comment: I've found an interesting thing. If I put full path like /Users/bc/..../cocos2dx/platform/android/java in project.properties, it doesn't recognises, but relative path works fine.